# Searching an Exchange Mailbox

Tags: search, mailbox

I've been searching all over without any specific answer that helps me.

Basically, I need to search a mailbox in our Exchange 2010 Server for a specific attachment. But due to the user accounts mailbox being so large, it is impossible to just manually do. I've tried using the Discovery Management Role and Search, but it keeps getting stuck. It has been running for the past week and hasn't found anything. We we've tried the search for just the hits, it states that it has found 5 instances.

If anyone can help me with any other way to search or to get this working, that would help me out a ton.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a GUI-driven way to do this:

http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exporting-mailboxes-content-using-exchange-management-console.html

Or, if you'd prefer powershell...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998579.aspx

Do these solve your problem, or are they methods you've tried? This has worked for me in the past.